# How can I merge parent and child observable in rxjs

Tags: javascript, typescript, rxjs

I have created a parent observable with a child observable. When the child observable completes it completes the parent observable.

Is there a nicer way to do this without having to use `subscripe()` twice.

Code:

```
const parentObservable = new Observable((observer) => {
  
  if (condition) {
     observer.complete();
     return;
  }

  this.childObservable().subscribe(() => observer.complete());
});

parentObservable.subscribe();
```

**EDIT:** We want to be able to not subscribe to the child if a condition is met

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to your description

> When the child observable completes it completes the parent observable.

I believe you could use [`takeUntil`](https://www.learnrxjs.io/learn-rxjs/operators/filtering/takeuntil).

```
const parentObservable = new Observable((observer) => { ... });

parentObservable.pipe(takeUntil(childObservable)).subscribe();
```

Whenever `childObservable` emits a value the pipe will complete and the teardown logic of `parentObservable` (if there is one) will be run.

---

Comment: This answer is almost perfect, the only problem is when I don't want to execute childobserver when a condition is met. Therefor I've changed my question slightly to include the early escape.

Comment: Since this answers my original question, and I don't believe my edited question to be possible to answer, I'm going to accept this one.

Comment: @Sandman You've got very special requirements ;) I believe this can not be achieved using a pipe. If you really need this, your current solution is the (or only?) possible I can think of.

Answer (score 2):

The merge operator allows you to merge multiple observables into a single observable. You can use this operator to merge the parent observable and the child observable.

```
const parentObservable = new Observable((observer) => {
  // random sync code
});

const childObservable = this.childObservable();

merge(parentObservable, childObservable).subscribe();
```

If you want to complete the parent observable when the child observable completes, you can use the concat operator instead. The concat operator will emit the values from the first observable, and then emit the values from the second observable once the first observable completes.

```
import { concat } from 'rxjs';

const combinedObservable = concat(parentObservable, childObservable);
combinedObservable.subscribe();
```

This will complete the parent observable when the child observable completes.

**merge** operator combines all the observables into a single stream and emits value as they come.

**concat** operator concatenate the observables and emits value only after the first observable completes.

Comment: Does this complete the parent when the child observer is completed like the code in the question?

Comment: I add the parent observable when the child observable completes, example also ;)

Comment: `merge` will only complete once _all_ it's inputs have completed and `concat` will only subscribe to `childObservable`, after `parentObservable` completes.

Comment: Thanks for your quick insightful answer!
So the concat works, the only problem I can't fix is the following

What if the //random sync code has `if (condition) { observer.complete(); return; }`, then the childobservable won't execute. In the concat it always does.

Comment: Ywlc,in this case you can use the switchMap operator to subscribe to childObservable only if the parentObservable has not completed yet.   const mergedObservable = parentObservable.pipe(
  switchMap(() => this.childObservable())
);

Answer (score 1):

Your example's `new Observable` constructor never emits any values, so it's going to be a pretty useless observable. You can just drop it and not worry about completing a useless observable.

Taking this into account, your example code can be re-written like this:

```ts
const parentObservable = defer(() => {
  if(condition){
    return EMPTY;
  }
  return this.childObservable();
});
parentObservable.subscribe();
```

This is conditionally subscribing to `childObservable`.
This can be simplified further as:

```ts
const parentObservable = defer(
  () => condition? EMPTY: this.childObservable()
);
parentObservable.subscribe();
```

or:

```ts
defer(() => condition? EMPTY: this.childObservable())
  .subscribe();
```

Comment: This is the answer to my problem locally. True I don't need an observable that doesn't emit.